# Chamada classe async Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gostaria de chamar uma classe que faz um post para um Endpoint mas que essa chamada não fosse bloqueante, pois ela está dentro de um evento que as vezes dispara 5 coorrencias seguidas e não posso esperar a conclusão do Post para continuar.

Fiz da seguinte maneira, mas estou com dificuldades em testar se realmente está funcionando

**Classe main.py**

```
"""
códigos que não interessa no exemplo
"""
from def_api import Api
api = Api('teste')
for item in range(10):   #for ficticio
   api.Send('valores')
```

**Classe def_api.py**

```
import requests

class Api(object)
   def __init__(self, valor1):
      self.__valor1 = valor1

   async def Send(self, valor2):
     self.__valor2 = valor2
     data = {'valor1': self.__valor1, 'valor2': self.__valor2}
     r = request.post(url, json=data)
     return await r.status_code
```

**Fiquei na dúvida:**
se o await deveria colocar no request,
r = await request.post...
ou se eu deveria tirar o await para ele não ficar bloqueante..

Peço ajuda, links, etc.

Comment: A chamada request.post() vai bloquear a thread principal mesmo que a função seja async. Teria de chamar "await request.post()" para não bloquear *E* request.post() teria de ser ela mesma uma função async, que eu acho que não é. Teria de usar threads ou, melhor ainda, asyncio para atingir este resultado. Esta pergunta do SO em inglês tem alguns exemplos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190403/how-could-i-use-requests-in-asyncio

Answer (score 2):

O `requests` é uma biblioteca síncrona - ou seja, nada do que você fizer vai permitir que o requests rode de forma não bloqueante e colaborativa com o asyncio, diretamente. Um caminho seria buscar no Pypi outras bibliotecas que emulam o requests, mas tem uma api assíncrona - por exemplo o [aiohttp-requests](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp-requests/).

No entanto, mesmo sem trocar o requests por outra lib, nem tudo está perdido: é justamente pra esses casos que o asyncio do Python inclui a chamada "run_in_executor" - basicamente, há uma forma de se criar um objeto "Executor" da biblioteca `concurrent.futures` que mantém um conjunto de threads (ou processos), e pode rodar as funções bloqueantes em uma dessas threads, fazendo com que a função que precisa desse resultado possa continuar de forma não bloqueante na thread principal.

A chamada `loop.run_in_executor` em si mesma se encarrega de despachar a função para o executor, e verificar o resultado  -a burocracia é mínima, bastando criar o objeto executor.

Documentação:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor

Não vou conseguir testar o código agora, mas  a princípio a adaptaçao do seu código fica algo como:

```py
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as Executor

# configura 20 requisições máximas em paralelo:

http_executor = Executor(20)

class Api(object)
   def __init__(self, valor1):
      self.__valor1 = valor1

   async def send(self, valor2):
     self.__valor2 = valor2
     data = {'valor1': self.__valor1, 'valor2': self.__valor2}
     loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
     r = await loop.run_in_executor(http_executor,  request.post, url, json=data)
     return r.status_code
```

(além da dica de como vai ser a camada do `run_in_executor`, mudei o nome do método para `send` em minúsculo em vez de `Send`, por que é a convenção em Python)

Comment: Se eu executar uma função bloqueante em uma thread, posso ter algum problema de limite de threads alcançada? devido algum limite Linux (cpu) ?

Comment: Threads nao são _muito_ eficientes, mas vai demorar um bocado você bater em algum limite - daria pra abrir centenas delas, sem problemas. Mas tem duas coisas: primeiro o tal do "Executor" do Python é muito bom em justamente cirar um tanto de workers (nesse exemplo, 20), e reutilizar esses workers conforme as demandas - u seja, mesmo com milhares de chamadas, o Python vai ficar reutilizando esses 20 workers - no momento em que chegar a 21 requisição e não tiver nenhum worker livre, ela vai ficar "esperando" automaticamente um acabar a tarefa. Essa é a ideia do `concurrent.futures`

Comment: E segundo, mesmo que você aumentasse o executor para usar centenas de workers, vai bater em algum outro gargalo antes - dependendo de outros fatores: sua banda de rede, por exemplo, mas, principamente, como o servidor do outro lado, pra onde está mandando o seu post, está dimensionado pra responder, ou limitar requisições vindas de um mesmo IP.
Não é incomum não se ter nenhum ganho além de 5 workers.

Comment: Mas em condições bem favoráveis, por exemplo, se você manda e recebe poucos dados, mas o cálculo da resposta demora do lado do servidor, _E_ o servidor remoto tem vários workers pra atender requisições diferentes, é possível que se tenha aumentos até um número bem grande de workers. (E você provavelmente estará consumindo uma quantidade de recursos do sistema remoto maior do que a pessoa dimensionou pra um único usuário - não estará sendo 'legal')